# Can I implement activity tracker using firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Someone knows if it can be possible on android or if I have to use Analytics, event and hit builders?

It is for tracking popular activities and fragments.

Sorry if it's a dumb question but i'm newbie and I don't know what summary and guide I have to follow for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.
You can do something like

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("activityName", getClass.getSimpleName());
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("startActivity", params);
```

You can read their documentation from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events)

Comment: Thanks so much. I think it's what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. but is it difference from gcm

```
public void sendScreenName(String screen){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, screen);
    FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).logEvent(screen.toLowerCase(),bundle);
}

public void sendUserProperties(String name, String value){
    FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setUserProperty(name.toLowerCase(),value);
}

public void sendSessionTimeOut(long time){
    FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setSessionTimeoutDuration(time);
}
```

Please make sure your screen name is lowercase or not contain digit/space/symbol. or it will not recorded